# Appending to 2d list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have 2 lists:

```
a = [222, 244, 231, 220, 200, 201, 202]
b = [[231, 220, 222, 244], [200, 201]]
```

I want to append all the values of a that are not in b as 1 item lists in the 2d list b. So since 202 is not in b the result should look like:

```
new_b = [[231, 220, 222, 244], [200, 201], [202]]
```

Seems like a straightforward problem but I am having trouble formulating a for loop to get it to work. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way using `set` and `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

b_set = set(chain.from_iterable(b))
res = b + [[i] for i in a if i not in b_set]

print(res)

[[231, 220, 222, 244], [200, 201], [202]]
```